# check if login was successful?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I compare local storage values with input values. If values are correct I want to print alert('login successful'). If not alert('login failed'). Because this is a loop i need to somehow check if alert('login successful') have fired. And if not. Print alert('login failed'). Any ideas?

```
login(){
    let data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'));

    for (let index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {    
      if(this.state.email === data[index].email && this.state.password === data[index].password){
          alert("login successful");
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Could you please post the entire code or create a codesandbox, or a jsFiddle? It's hard to understand your app and behavior based on this code, how does your `data` look like? why do you iterate the data object?

Comment: My code is irrelevant because my inputs and local storage works. I just needed help with  for loop logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep track of if the login was successful or not with a variable, and check the value of this variable after the loop to see what you should alert.

```
login() {
  const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data"));
  let isSuccessful = false;

  for (let index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
    if (
      this.state.email === data[index].email &&
      this.state.password === data[index].password
    ) {
      isSuccessful = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (isSuccessful) {
    alert("login successful");
  } else {
    alert("login failed");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If this matches the email and pwd show successful dialog and returns

else show unsuccessful dialog

```
login() {
  let data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'));

  for (let index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
    if (this.state.email === data[index].email && this.state.password === data[index].password) {
      alert("login successful");
      return;
    }
  }
  alert("login Unsuccessful");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a variable to the loop which checks if the login was successful?

```
login(){
    let data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'));
    let loginSuccessfull = false;

    for (let index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {    
      if(this.state.email === data[index].email && this.state.password === data[index].password){
          alert("login successful");
          loginSuccessfull = true;
      }
    }
    if(!loginSuccessfull) {
        alert("login failed");
    }

  }
```